# dynamical set read only in infopath 2010

Tags: infopath2010

I'm new to infopath and I have a form with several views, the view shown is controlled by a field usertype which set in a workflow and has an int value (1 = requester, 2 = Sales, 3 = product...)  so if I set usertype to 2 the form loads with the sales view which is how it should work, but what I need to do is set all the other views to read only so the sales person can view the data in all views but ONLY change the date presented in his view i.e. the sales view.

so how can build a rule or add c# code to achieve setting a views property to read only depending on the value of usertype?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the view drop-down in the ribbon, so you have control over which views can be accessed in particular situations.

Create read-only versions of each of the three views. Use buttons on the editable forms to show the read only versions of the other two views.

Comment: Thanks, Is their a quick way to copy a complete view?

Comment: Create a new view. Switch to the existing view. Select All with Ctrl-A, copy with Ctrl-C, switch to the new view, select All with Ctrl-A, paste the clipboard with Ctrl-V. Standard procedure, like in all Office applications, really.

Comment: Ok thanks :-) didn't know if it would copy over all the fields names etc, will try it when back at work... Cheers

Comment: within the same IP form, the controls are bound to the data source and can easily be copied between different views of the form. After all, a view is just -- a view.